# Aurelia - javascript/Typescript - Issue where typeahead calls a function before a promise is returned leading to error

Tags: javascript, typescript, aurelia

It all works until you clear the typeahead field and then I get an error in the function `suburbSelected(item)` (shown below) as the promise has not been resolved before the typeahead calls this function. The full error I am getting - two of them are as follows:

```
  Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'postcode' of null
    at Address.app / components / clients / address / address.Address.suburbSelected(address.ts:126)
    at CallScope.evaluate(aurelia - binding.js:1524)
    at Call.callSource(aurelia - binding.js:4961)
    at AubsTypeaheadCustomElement.<anonymous>(aurelia - binding.js:4985)
    at aubs- typeahead.js:227
    at < anonymous >
        app / components / clients / address / address.Address.suburbSelected @ address.ts: 126
    evaluate @ aurelia-binding.js:1524
    callSource @ aurelia-binding.js:4961
        (anonymous) @ aurelia-binding.js:4985
            (anonymous) @ aubs-typeahead.js:227
    Promise.then(async)
    filterChanged @ aubs-typeahead.js:222
    descriptor.set @ aurelia-binding.js:5455
    assign @ aurelia-binding.js:1398
    assign @ aurelia-binding.js:1174
    updateSource @ aurelia-binding.js:4830
        (anonymous) @ debounce-binding - behavior.js:16
    setTimeout(async)
    debounce @ debounce-binding - behavior.js:15
    call @ aurelia-binding.js:4852
    callSubscribers @ aurelia-binding.js:304
    notify @ aurelia-binding.js:3849
    handleEvent @ aurelia-binding.js:3855


  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'postcode' of null
    at Address.app / components / clients / address / address.Address.suburbSelected(address.ts:126)
    at CallScope.evaluate(aurelia - binding.js:1524)
    at Call.callSource(aurelia - binding.js:4961)
    at AubsTypeaheadCustomElement.<anonymous>(aurelia - binding.js:4985)
    at AubsTypeaheadCustomElement.itemSelected(aubs - typeahead.js:356)
    at CallScope.evaluate(aurelia - binding.js:1524)
    at Listener.callSource(aurelia - binding.js:5113)
    at Listener.handleEvent(aurelia - binding.js:5122)
    at HTMLDocument.handleDelegatedEvent(aurelia - binding.js:3237)
```

Here is the typeahead fetch for the suburbs:

```
    let suburbLookup = fetch("/api/selectData/QuerySuburbs" + queryString, {
        method: "GET",
        headers: headers
    })
        .then(response => {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(addressLocation => {
            if (this.address.addressLocation == null) {
                console.log("ADDRESSLOCATION BEFORE: ", this.address.addressLocation)
                this.address.addressLocation = new AddressLocation;
                console.log("ADDRESSLOCATION AFTER: ", this.address.addressLocation)
            }
                return addressLocation;
        })
        .then(addressLocation => filter.length > 0 ? addressLocation.filter(item => item.suburb.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter.toLowerCase()) > -1) : addressLocation)
        .then(addressLocation => limit ? addressLocation.splice(0, limit) : addressLocation);  // Not really needed - its done on the server.
    //.then(suburbs => console.log("Suburbs: ", suburbs));

    //this.postCode = this.address.postcode;

    console.log("suburbLookup", suburbLookup);
    return suburbLookup
}
```

Here is the typeahead with all its attributes:

```
                    <aubs-typeahead data.call="getSuburbData(filter, limit)"
                                    value.bind="address.addressLocation"
                                    debounce.bind="350"
                                    placeholder="Suburb..."
                                    open-on-focus.bind="true"
                                    key="suburb"
                                    results-limit.bind="10"
                                    select-single-result.bind="true"
                                    on-select.call="suburbSelected(item)"
                                    id="suburbAutocomplete">
                    </aubs-typeahead>
```

You will note that there is an attribute called `on-select.call="suburbSelected(item)"`

Its in suburbSelected(item) where the error occurs. Here is that function:

```
suburbSelected(item) {
      console.log("BEFORE ASSIGNMENT OF SUBURB NAME: ", item, item.postcode, this.address.addressLocation.postcode) //THIS IS LINE 126...
      if (item) {
        this.address.addressLocation.postcode = item.postcode;
      } else {
          this.address.addressLocation.postcode = "-";
      }
  }
```

How do I intelligently wait until the promise has been completed before the function `suburbSelected(item)` is run? If it waits for the promise to be returned I believe it wont error... is there a nice Typescript/Javascript way of making this function wait for another promise to resolve??

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from the code you posted, how fetch is called, but I'm sure you can sidestep the problem with async/await

```
   async getData(filter:any){  // your fetch data method
        let result = await Promise.resolve({a:'b'})  // magic happens here

        return result
    }
```

Comment: Still pretty new to this.. so the drop down happens and then you select an option and tahts when it throws an error. How do I add this piece of code.. do I add it to the suburbSelectedItem function etc its automatically called by the typeahead... thanks for replying.

Comment: I added async to the fetch function as well as await to the actual fetch and I am still getting  the error "address.ts:130 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'postcode' of null" - thats associated with the suburbSelected(item) function

Comment: it seems that .addressLocation is null can you place a `debugger;` inside the function that is called on select? and see what you have there?
also, why you use .call ?